# Tensorflow: Compute inverse counts of labels

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a tensor `labels` of shape (b,n) of integers with values in [0,1,2,3,4,5].
I want to create a tensor `weights` of shape (b,n) that carries at position (i,j) the inverse of the number of times that the integer `labels[i,j]` occurs in labels.

Working example code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
tf.InteractiveSession()
labels=tf.convert_to_tensor(np.array([[1,0,0,1,2,4],[2,2,2,4,2,1]]), dtype=tf.int32)
weights=tf.ones_like(labels, dtype=tf.float32)
bc=tf.bincount(labels, minlength=6, maxlength=6)
for i in range(6):
    cur_count = 1.0/(1e-10+tf.cast(bc[i], tf.float32))
    count_tensor = tf.ones_like(labels, dtype=tf.float32)*cur_count
    weights = tf.where(tf.equal(labels,i), count_tensor, weights)
weights.eval()
# array([[0.3333, 0.5, 0.5, 0.3333, 0.2, 0.5],
#        [0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.5, 0.2, 0.3333]], dtype=float32)
```

So for example, the label `1` appears three times in the `labels` tensor so that in `weights` the value 1/3 appears at each position, where a `1` is in `labels`.

Now what I don't like about this code is that tf.bincount does not work on the GPU in my tensorflow version (1.4.0) and I cannot update.
Also, I am not sure how the for loop is handled by tensorflow and how much overhead is created by this.

I suppose that there is a more elegant solution to my problem. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

About the loop, you can replace it with a call to `tf.gather`:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

tf.InteractiveSession()
labels = tf.convert_to_tensor(
    np.array([[1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 4], [2, 2, 2, 4, 2, 1]]), dtype=tf.int32)
bc = tf.bincount(labels, minlength=6, maxlength=6)
weights = tf.gather(1.0 / (1e-10 + tf.cast(bc, tf.float32)), labels)
print(weights.eval())
```

Output:

```
[[0.33333334 0.5        0.5        0.33333334 0.2        0.5       ]
 [0.2        0.2        0.2        0.5        0.2        0.33333334]]
```

About `tf.bincount` being CPU-only, that does not seem to be the case currently. In fact, a GPU implementation seems to have been available [since v1.5.0](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v1.5.0/tensorflow/core/kernels/bincount_op_gpu.cu.cc).

If you wanted an alternative implementation, you could do something like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

tf.InteractiveSession()
labels = tf.convert_to_tensor(
    np.array([[1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 4], [2, 2, 2, 4, 2, 1]]), dtype=tf.int32)
eq = tf.equal(labels[:, :, tf.newaxis], tf.range(6, dtype=labels.dtype))
bc = tf.reduce_sum(tf.cast(eq, tf.float32), axis=[0, 1])
weights = tf.gather(1.0 / (1e-10 + tf.cast(bc, tf.float32)), labels)
print(weights.eval())
# Same output
```

However `tf.bincount` is likely to be more efficient than this.

Comment: I am currently stuck with tensorflow 1.4.0 because of some CUDA dependencies so I cannot use the gpu version of bincount. Do you think the CPU version of bincount is faster than your proposed other solution with `tf.equal`?

Comment: @Merlin1896 Ah didn't read that right in the question. I honestly cannot tell, then. Besides the actual implemented algorithm, depends on many things, the actual hardware, the size of the tensors, etc. A mixed GPU/CPU graph will have the overhead of moving data from one device to another, but my second solution surely takes more memory too. Shouldn't be too hard to make a small benchmark (with realistic sizes) to get an idea of how they compare...